# Offset viewable image in <img> tags the same way as for background-image

Tags: html, css

Using plain <img> tags is it possible to offset the image in the same way as you can with CSS background-image and background-position?

There are main images on the page and it makes little sense to have separate thumbnails when both will be loaded (thus increasing bandwidth). Some of the images are portrait and some are landscape, however I need to display the thumbnails at a uniform size (and crop off the excess where it fails to meet the desired aspect ratio).

Although this is possible using other tags and background- CSS values the use of plain <img> tags would be preferable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an old question, but it was the first one that came up when I googled the question, so I thought I would mention the answer that, in my opinion, actually solves the original problem how to emulate `background-position` attribute. The answer I found is to use CSS attributes `object-position` and `object-fit`. For example like this:

```
<img src="logos.png" style="object-fit: none; object-position: -64px 0; width: 32px; height: 32px" />
```

This will show the third thumbnail in the first row (assuming the thumbnails are arranged in a regular grid 32 x 32 pixels).

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately no, it's not possible with only an `<img>` tag.  There are 2 solutions I can think of to your problem:

**CSS background-image**

Create a `<div>` where the image is applied as a background-image property:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="background: url(an-image.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%"></div>
```

**CSS clipping**

Use the `clip-path` property to only show a section of the image:

```
<!-- Clip properties are top, right, bottom, left and define a rectangle by its top-left and bottom-right points -->
<div style="clip-path: inset(10px 200px 200px 10px)">
    <img src="an-image.jpg">
</div>
```

You can read more about it [in this article](http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/).

Comment: The wrong way to do it. At least, if you send your content to a HOTMAIL account. Hotmail only displays images, not divs with images. A simple way is to use the native img property clip:rect(0px,100px,100px,0px). Very simple. Just DO NOT put it inside an overflow:hidden div. See the property on w3schools.

Comment: beware, support for `clip-path` [is pretty weak](https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path/embed)

Comment: ...and “50% 50%” is a guess, better use [`background-size: cover`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 8):

If you put the image in a div you can use the margins to move the image around.  This particular example use a sprite image logo for the home link that changes position on hover.  You could also skip the A tag and move the image around using the margin attribute on #logo img.

The HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/src.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#logo { 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 15px 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 350px; //portion of the image you wish to display
    height: 50px; //portion of the image you wish to display
    overflow: hidden; //hide the rest of the image
}
#logo img {
    width: 350px; 
    height: 100px; // you'll see this is 2x the height of the viewed image
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
#logo a { 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
#logo a:hover { 
    margin-top: -50px;  //move up to show the over portion of the image
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Before

```
<img src="img.png"> Text, Links, Etc
```

After:

```
<img src="img.png" style="float:left; margin-bottom:-5px"> Text, Links, Etc
```

Read about Block-Formatting context on W3C.

Comment: You are correct. `quid`'s answer is overkill. Even `float:left` was not necessary in my case. A simple negative margin adjustment is all that is required to slide the element's viewing area to the left or right -- but it might be necessary to combine with height/width dimensions for the img tag.  A fiddle (or stack-snippet) would be a good idea for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Some of the images are portrait and some are landscape, however I need to display the thumbnails at a uniform size (and crop off the excess where it fails to meet the desired aspect ratio).

Use `background-size: cover` which should [**exactly** solve that problem](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) → with [good browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)!

And make you image the background (probably using `background-image` as an inline style):

```html
<img style="background-image: url('img/foo.png')"/>
```