# Change image onclick-events

Tags: dart

How do I implement a button on-click event with loading different images?

I want to show different images in one div-container. If I click on the button "changeImage" it should change the picture.

How can I implement this in dart language?

Update: A new image should be loaded by each click. The images are in one file.

Do I call the img with a Button like this?

```
    <input type="button" value="button" ng-click="img">
```

Comment: I bit more details would be helpful. Should a new image be loaded after each click or do you load them all at once but just want to show one of them at a time. If you wan't them to load after each click, where do you want to load them from how do you generate the URIs?

Comment: What do you mean by 'images are in one file'? `ng-click` indicates that you are using AngularDart, is that so? If you really have one file with several images as it is often done to minimize the number of requests to load several images in one go you have to use one of the strategies shown in the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348881)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on the answer to my comment above there are different ways to do it.

(not tested)

```dart
import 'dart:async';

const NUM_IMAGES = 4;

main() {
  int curImg = 1;

  (querySelectorAll('img') as HtmlElement).forEach((img) {
    img.onClick.listen((e) {
    (querySelector('#img_${curImg % 4}') as HtmlElement).classes.add('hidden');
    curImg++;
    (querySelector('#img_${curImg % 4}') as HtmlElement).classes.remove('hidden');
  });
}
```

.

```dart
<style>
 img.hidden {
   display: none;
 }
</style>
<img id="img_1" src="a.gif" >
<img id="img_2" src="b.gif" class="hidden">
<img id="img_3" src="c.gif" class="hidden">
<img id="img_4" src="d.gif" class="hidden">
```

---

alternative solution:

```dart
List<String> uris = ['/img/img_a.gif', '/img/img_b.gif', '/img/img_c.gif', '/img/img_d.gif'];

main() {
  int curImg = 0;
  (imgElement = querySelector('img') as ImageElement).onClick.listen((img) {
    curImg++;
    imgElement.src = uris[curImg];
  });
}
```

.

```dart
<img>
```

Comment: Thanks Günter! I will try your solutions out.

Comment: If I try the first solution I get an                             
Error:Breaking on exception: Class 'ImageElement' has no instance method 'forEach'.

Comment: Sorry, forgot querySelector**All**

Comment: My answer doesn't show how to update the image when you click on a button but when you click on the image. But you just have to query for the button instead of the image when assigning the event handler.