# Background-size and background-position on an img tag

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image that can be cropped used a JS lib. The lib returns x,y, width and height of the selection.

Initially, the logic was just several uploaded image (in `<img>`) sit side by side with little edit buttons over them that open a pop-up with the cropping logic. However, now the specification is to have the preview of what was cropped.

The question - is there a way to do it without switching all `<img>` to `<div>`s that will have all images as background and can be moved and scaled to show the cropped part? Is there a counterpart to such styling or another possible workaround in which I can keep the `<img>` tags?

Comment: How does a preview of what was cropped work? Would the cropped item show up somewhere on another image?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Let's say there is an image 300px by 500px. The user needs the 50px 50px portion located in the center. He selects it and I place this 50px-50px portion (stretching it, if required) into the original image container, so the user is sure that only this portion of the image is used.

Comment: Probably a canvas will be your best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is by using any html element in combination with the css background attribute. Within that attribute you can define margins as sizes to position and resize the background image. In your case that element would have the width and the height given by your crop library. The position of the background image would be x and y (also from the library), but inverted.

It does not matter which element you use, it can be any (See [w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html)), included an img tag as shown in the [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/wsjftz8d/):

```
<img border="0" style="display:block; width:120px; height:120px; background-color:red; padding:9px; background:url(http://www2.cnrs.fr/sites/communique/image/mona_unvarnish_web_image.jpg) no-repeat; background-position:-100px -40px;" />
```

Note that if you use the image tag you have to remove the `src` attribute (e.g. by JavaScript). Otherwise the background image will not be visible.

Nevertheless I would recommend you to use a JavaScript Library / Plugin instead of writing it something by your own. There are a bunch of solutions:

- [JCrop (jQuery Plugin)](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/)
- [ImageAreaSelect (jQuery Plugin](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)
- [Uvumitools Crop (Mootools Plugin)](http://uvumitools.com/crop.html)
- [JS Cropper UI (Based on scriptacolous and prototype)](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Not the exact solution, but I learned something from it. Ended up re-writing and adding an extra div to an image. I put events on all of my images that were triggered if an image was displaying an error, so when I remove the 'src' the error displays and I did not want to override it.

Answer (score 32):

If you don't care about IE you can use `object-fit` and `object-position`:

```css
img {
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center top;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20668068)

Comment: Ok. I have removed the link. Two lines of code is much better many words.

Comment: FYI - **[No IE support at all.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)**

Comment: Life savior... Thanks a lot

Comment: LOL. This answer was very close to be deleted in 2018 because of IE. But every year it becomes more and more popular. RIP IE

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple way. If included a link to one answer below that agrees. You could use javscript to render part of the image to a canvas then use the answer I've posted under (Canvas Approach) below to set the resulting image into the image tag src attribute.

Concurring Answer:
[Offset viewable image in <img> tags the same way as for background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348881/offset-viewable-image-in-img-tags-the-same-way-as-for-background-image)

Canvas Approach:
[Can I get image from canvas element and use it in img src tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag)