# How to align an image within an <img> tag?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Is there a possibility to align an image within its `<img>` tag?

Just to be clear, I do *not* want to align the `<img>` tag but the image inside that tag.

Example:

I have an image:

```
<img id="image" src="image.png" alt=""/>
```

And define a specific size for the tag:

```
#image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Though image.png is just 200 x 100 pixels big. How to align it at the top left corner of the `<img>` tag?

I've tried it via CSS using `text-align: left; vertical-align: top;` and `display: flex; justify-content: start; align-items: start;` and via HTML using `align="top left"`.
I found a hacky way via `box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0 0 100px 100px;`, though that requires to calculate the exact amount of pixels needed to move the image to a side or a corner.

Comment: Align the image to the top left corner of what?

Comment: Of the <img> tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348881/offset-viewable-image-in-img-tags-the-same-way-as-for-background-image

Comment: The `img` tag _is_ the image...

Comment: No, the `<img>` tag only holds the image. It could also be a `<canvas>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just posted the question, already found the answer. You need to use the CSS properties [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).

Explanation: Images are replaced elements and those to properties allow to influence the sizing and position of replaced elements.

So positioning the image at the top left corner works like this:

```css
#image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: top left;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Turns out it was me who initially documented those two properties on MDN some years ago. \*blush\* Totally forgot them when stumbling over this use case again.

Answer (score 3):

What u are expecting is not possible, `<img>` in one tag, which holds your image, there is nothing inside it.

If i am not wrong you are expecting some thing similar to the below working snippet, which is symantically correct

```css
figure {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png/369/fff" alt="Image" width="100" height="100">
</figure>
```

[OR]
you can use `background-image` within a `img` tag as shown below,  hope it helps :)

```css
#image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100.png/369/fff") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="" alt=""/>
```

Comment: @Quentin please have a look at the second snippet which uses your own markup, with few modifications to the `id` css, hope that answers your question :)

Comment: Obviously, [there is a clean solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893167/432681) to it without having to wrap the image into a container element or use a background image instead.